# Unable to access Checkout from Shopify Storefront Api

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api, storefront, shopify-storefront-api

I'm trying to run mutation on my Shopify store for calculating the Shipping zone price to gross total, I'm using "checkoutShippingLineUpdate" for that but when I'm running Below query to fetch it shows "Unable to access checkout"

```
mutation MyMutation {
  checkoutShippingLineUpdate(checkoutId: "", shippingRateHandle: "Same day delivery") {
    checkout {
      id
      lineItems {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
    checkoutUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add the Shipping zone rate to the gross total.